# Is Gandalf really on 'du' terms with the Balrog? (Odd 'duzen' example)

Tags: informal

Gandalf's line "You shall not pass!" from *The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring* is something of a meme, so I naturally wondered how it was translated into German. [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZmhBhfY3t9E) has the relevant dialog (once at :40, and again at 1:15). Gandalf says "*Du kannst nicht vorbei!*"

There are a few issues here. First, no infinitive verb with the modal verb. It seems to be common in German to drop "gehen/kommen" from the end when you use a modal verb with an adverb or prepositional phrase indicating direction. So the verb is not actually required here.

Second, the German uses *können* instead of the future tense as in the English version. To me this changes the meaning somewhat, and the "shall" is significant in light of what happens next. But perhaps this is a matter of interpretation.

What I'm stuck on is why Gandalf uses the 'du' form in this speech. The grammars say that the 'du' form is used for friends and family members, sometimes children and pets. So I would have thought "*Sie können nicht vorbei!*"

My first idea is that since the Balrog does not speak, it's taken to be some kind of animal. To me, this doesn't fit the story; the Balrog is a kind of demon and is intelligent despite being unwilling or unable to speak in the scene. Plus you don't see many animals wielding whips. My second idea is that Gandalf is being deliberately *unhöflich* by using 'du'. Perhaps this is to distract the Balrog, bait it into trying to cross the bridge, or just to show his contempt. Are either of these likely or is there another explanation?

Comment: I was since ever under the impression that "Thou shall not pass" was used in the movie. Yet this discussion says otherwise: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/35262/where-did-you-shall-not-pass-come-from. So my entire argument collapses. Beyond that I simply see the English in easy win with it's both you and you. And to say "Sie A...och" is quite less common.

Comment: Translating movie dialog has to respect the syllable structure of the original wording, particularly when the speaker is featured as dramatically as Gandalf here. Therefore, it is often *not* representative of what an original work in another language would have said.

Comment: A video is in my opinion a source lacking authority in respect to translation, since there are additional restrictions to be handled due to lip synchronisation issues. This is similar to the meter restrictions in poetry. Can anybody supply the quote from one of the German translations of the book?

Comment: @guidot: see answer from Paul Frost available since now^^

Comment: The other way round. In the later translation by Krege Sam says Sie zu Frodo, as he's only the gardener. Theres some funny usage due to the translation. Still, as a German, you don't say Sie when you approach a foe.

Comment: My wife assures me that Gandalf used "du" as an intentional affront.

Comment: @RBarryYoung I do not think you can say this. Only in the German translation this **could** be possible, but Tolkien's English text does not allow this conclusion.

Comment: I can't speak much about German (although my language also has a du/Sie thing), but being polite with the enemy in middle of a death fight doesn't seem appropiate.

Comment: The English version from the movie with *shall* is **NOT** “future tense” (which English doesn’t have). There is no tense here at all: it is a command, an imperative. This therefore is a normal modal verb being in the [deontic modality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modality_(natural_language)) of obligations and permissions rather than in the epistemic mode of possibility. All modal verbs are bimodally deontic-vs-epistemic, including German modals, not just English ones.  And the reason they added *shall* in the film was to hearken back to Biblical commandments like *Thou shalt not X*.

Comment: @tchrist: I think there are different possible interpretations of "shall" here. You *can* use "shall" for future tense; it's somewhat dated and formal now but Gandalf always talks like that. Both English and German form a future tense with auxiliary verbs (will/shall & *werden*) rather than with inflections, but that doesn't mean they don't have them. You can also use "shall" as a modal verb, and the meaning of the line is open to interpretation. I was thinking more along the lines of MacArthur's "I shall return" rather than the bible.

Comment: "Thou shalt not commit murder" is not some "future tense" thing. If you want to call anything that talks about the future "future tense", you're welcome to do that of course. But it is very confusing to people who actually use that term to mean a synthetic/morphological inflection as we see happen in Latin and her daughter tongues. Germanic languages will not do that even if you ask them nicely—that's "will" deontic not epistemic because they refuse. It is not "future tense". Notice also how "He will have left by now" is actually talking the past not the future. There's no future tense there.

Comment: @tchrist, it's also confusing to call it an imperative, given how different "You shall not pass" (as used in this scene) is from a hypothetical alternative line - "Do not pass", which would be the classic imperative form.

Comment: @cruthers: Both English and German have multiple ways of expressing an imperative other than a grammatical imperative; most of the time it's because the undisguised imperative is considered harsh or rude. I think *Ich möchte, dass du nicht passt.* & *Würdest du bitte nicht passen?* are possible but totally inappropriate under the circumstances :)

Comment: @RDBury, that's kind of my point - I was responding to the fine grammatical points stated above that suggest that "future tense" is confusing, but which would by the same logic also support that "imperative" is confusing. My own view is that "you shall not pass" can be described as a mix of the two - it is imperative exactly because it states the future of the Balrog with the added implication that Gandalf will enforce that future!

Comment: I don't think there was much choice. Using "Ihr" (let alone "Sie") would just sound wrong for a dialog between a wizard and a monster. [Doctor Strange and Dormammu](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pD1TbO6EEZY) for example use "du" as well, there is just no other idiomatic way.

Comment: @guidot: Matching lip-flaps better might actually be part of the motivation for the choice of "du" *for the movie*.  It would be interesting if book translations chose different phrasing.  (If other dialogue is also different from any book translation, that would be a weaker signal.)

Comment: I'm surprised it was translated using any modal verb at all.  The sense I get from the prophetic-sounding "you shall not..." is that it is a challenge—something that might be rendered in modern English as "you're not getting past me".  As such I would have expected the German translation "Du *kommst* nicht vorbei" to capture it. Admittedly the archaic English "shall" makes it sound grander and more dramatic, but "kannst" equally bursts that balloon.

Comment: Does anybody know whether Smaug is "geduzt" in "The Hobbit"?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In a fantasy setting it is quite uncommon to use *Sie*. You would use *du* or the *pluralis majestatis* form *Ihr*

So the question would rather be, why is Gandalf saying

> Du kannst nicht vorbei!

instead of

> Ihr könnt nicht vorbei!

You are right that animals would be addressed as *du* in German and, furthermore, that the Balrog cannot be considered an animal. At least I would consider saying *Ihr* to a powerful evil spirit, so as not to anger it.
However, diving into the depths of Tolkien's world, Gandalf and the Balrog go back to the same race (the primordial spirits, Maia).  As such, it could be argued that Gandalf is somehow familiar with it (and he knows that the Balrog is to be expected in the mines) and as such chose the *du* form. In that way he also implies he's on the same level, if not above it, and emphasizes this with his words.
Another argument would be that the Balrog was already angered and that it was not really time to use courtesies.

However, this could be deemed too much of an interpretation and the truth could simply be that the translator didn't care much about this particular translation.

To address the question about *können*:

The way it is emphasized in the movie, it does not mean

> You are unable to pass.

But rather

> You are not allowed to pass *Du darfst nicht vorbei*

Which agrees with *You shall not pass*.

Comment: I like the idea that Gandalf is emphasizing that he "outranks" the Balrog as Maia. Perhaps the idea was to use this show of disrespect to shake the Balrog's confidence. It's also possible I'm putting more thought into this than the translator did, but I like this interpretation so that's what I'm going with. To me, the "shall" is Galdalf's way of casting magic onto the bridge. If the Balrog tried to cross then the spell would cause something to happen to prevent it, and in fact the bridge collapses. You could also interpret it as denying permission, but that wouldn't make the bridge fall.

Comment: It is interesting that we are discussing the German translation, not the English original text which does not allow to make a distinction between "Du" and "Sie / Ihr". The question is therefore about the translator's **interpretation**: Why did she use "Du"? Are there any hints in Tolkien's book which justifies the use of "Du" instead of "Ihr"?

Comment: @Kritiker der Elche: I have thought about that myself. I'm making the assumption that the translator knows German better than I do, which isn't hard. And I'm also taking into account that there are a lot of German speaking Tolkien fans who would complain if the translation sounded odd or unexpected. I think all translations add and subtract from the original, and similarly movie versions of books add and subtract from the original, so we're a long way from Tolkien's intent here. Still, I'd like to believe that there is *some* interpretation of the line that makes sense "in universe".

Comment: I was under the impression that 'du' might be used as a deliberate form of disrespect.  Gandalf certainly doesn't care if he angers the Balrog or not; that ship has already sailed.

Comment: Alternative script:  
Gandalf: "Du ka... sorry... Sie können nicht vorbei!"  
Balrog: "Well, okay then, if you say so politely. Have a nice trip."

Comment: @KritikerderElche It _is_ interesting that Tolkien didn't use the archaic informal pronoun "thou" here

Comment: @Spencer Does Tolkien use "thou" anywhere in his book?

Comment: @KritikerderElche Yes; [here are some examples](https://www.reddit.com/r/tolkienfans/comments/1x9pw8/use_of_thou_in_lotr/).

Comment: @JFBM “I’m disinclined to acquiesce to your request of passage over this bridge. I’m afraid if you insist on continuing on this path, it could lead to an argument.”

Comment: +1  Gandalf and the Balrog, being both Maiar, are basically akin to something like feuding brothers, so the familiar form, of course, makes the most sense.

Comment: "Darfst nicht" is not an improvement. To take a modern day example, there's a big difference between being told "you can't park here" and being told "you're not parking here".  The former (whether with "can" or "may") merely states that a restriction exists. The latter carries greater menace, as it implies that the speaker (a) intends to enforce the restriction and (b) is confident enough of success to be able to predict *your* future actions.  That menace, conveyed by the English "shall not", is lost somewhat in "cannot" ("kannst nicht") but even more so if you use "may not" ("darfst nicht").

Comment: It would be interesting to analyze when "Du" and "Ihr" are used in the German translation. I didn't read again the whole text, but it seems to me that Gandalf only uses "Ihr" when talking to really high-ranking persons like Elrond. The Hobbits, for example, are "geduzt". I can't judge whether this corresponds to the original English text (you vs. thou), but we can certainly say that Gandalf does not regard the Balrog as a  high-ranking person.

Answer (score 38):

Others have already given good answers, but I thought I'd elaborate a bit more on the difference of "Du" vs "Sie".

The thing is - "Sie" is used when trying to show respect. There is no direct equivalent in the English language, <s>although if I understand correctly, the old-fashioned "thou" used to fill this role</s><sup>1</sup>. Instead you could imagine that using "Sie" is like adding a honorific like "Sir" or "Mr". It is used when talking to strangers when you wish to be polite to them, or when talking to superiors.

In contrast, "Du" is the default mode of address. It is not insulting or overly familiar, but it also doesn't add any extra respect. You normally use it for people whom you know personally (family, friends, colleagues, etc) where the respect is already implied and you don't need an extra demonstration of it. You can use it on strangers too, but it becomes very informal. Not impolite, but also not explicitly polite. In English that would be similar to calling someone by their first name, instead of "Mr. Smith" or something.

So, if Gendalf had used *"Sie können nicht vorbei!"* then it would have sounded like "Sir, you shall not pass!" Kinda weirdly respectful towards someone trying to kill you. :)

<sup>1</sup><sub>Correction from the comments - it's the other way round. "Thou" used to be the familiar form while "you" used to be the polite, respectful form. However the English language evolved to use "you" for both.</sub>

Comment: This is the correct answer. Translating it as "Sie" would essentially back-translate as "Sir, with all due respect, you can't pass. Sorry, just saying." -- we don't use "Sie" where respect isn't given.

Comment: This is good to know. I've noticed that grammars and language courses & textbooks tend to stress polite forms over familiar forms for any language that has both. Presumably this is because they're geared toward travelers, and authors and teachers don't want to get complaints. Polite forms have the advantage of being not wrong, even if they're not completely right.

Comment: I wonder how the times that Tolkien really does *thou* forms correctly can be accurately translated. He deliberately tells us in his guise as pseudo-translator: "In one or two places an attempt has been made to hint at these distinctions by an inconsistent use of *thou*. Since this pronoun is now unusual and archaic it is employed mainly to represent the use of ceremonious language; but a change from *you* to *thou, thee* is sometimes meant to show, there being no other means of doing this, a significant change from the deferential, or between men and women normal, forms to the familiar."

Comment: "*in the English language the old-fashioned "thou" used to fill this role*" - from my understanding, it's the other way round. *Du* = *Thou* and *Sie* = *You*, only the usage evolved differently.

Comment: @Bergi - Ahh, I think you are right.  My bad, I'll correct it!

Comment: @Tom Sie would have been a completely wrong translation not for the reason above, but because this kind of language is not used in fantasy settings.

Comment: @infinitezero that's not generally true. It depends on the author and/or translator. I've absolutely seen "Sie" in fantasy settings. Not everyone tries to be "period" by using "Ihr" and "Euch".

Answer (score 17):

In the German translation of Tolkien's "The Lord of the Rings" one does nowhere find  the modern polite form *Sie*, but the old-fashioned *Ihr*. Why is that? I think the use of *Ihr* wants to indicate that all this happened a very long time ago.

The phrase *Du kannst nicht vorbei!* is taken from Margaret Carroux's German translation of Tolkien's books. See Band 1 (Die Gefährten), Buch 2, Kapitel 5 (Die Brücke von Khazad-dûm). In the Klett-Cotta Edition from 1987 you can find it on p. 399.

In my opinion it would have been better to say *Du kommst nicht vorbei* instead of completely omitting the verb *kommen*. Anyway, your main question is why the Balrog is *geduzt* by Gandalf. The books definitely uses both *Du* and *Ihr* to adress persons (i.e. human beings, hobbits, elves, dwarfs) and so do the films. See [here](http://www.filmzitate.info/index-link1.php?link=http://www.filmzitate.info/suche/film-zitate.php?film_id=567), for example "Ihr seht viel, Eómer, Eómunds Sohn, zu viel". Even Samweis uses "Herr Frodo" and "Ihr".

I suspect that other creatures are never adressed by the polite "Ihr", especially if they belong to the "evil empire": They do not deserve respect or reverence.

**Update:**

Here is the [English original text](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/546473-the-balrog-reached-the-bridge-gandalf-stood-in-the-middle):

> There was a ringing clash and a stab of white fire. The Balrog fell back and its sword flew up in molten fragments. The wizard swayed on the bridge, stepped back a pace, and then again stood still.
> **'You cannot pass!'** he said.
> With a bound the Balrog leaped full upon the bridge. Its whip whirled and hissed.

This explains the translation *Du kannst nicht vorbei* .

Comment: I noticed watching the German version of The Witcher that they used the "Ihr" form a lot, not just to royalty but to anyone who wasn't obviously a criminal. I'm not surprised that Sam would *ihrzen* Frodo; though they are friends they are definitely in a master/servant relationship. I think they even play this up in the movies by giving Sam a West Country accent while Frodo uses Received Pronunciation. The idea that the "good guys" would use *du* with the bad guys goes with the idea that Gandalf was showing contempt, or at least disrespect.

Comment: Re the update: You're right, the book uses "can" instead of "shall". There are many other differences: In the book Gandalf says the line four times, not just twice; Aragorn and Boromir start to rush toward Gandalf, but in the movie they hang back; and the list goes on. I was assuming that movie translation would be from the movie dialog and not the book, though it seems likely now that Carroux's translation had at least some influence.

Comment: RDBury More than that, Frodo is always "Mister Frodo" to Sam. That's simply a direct translation. Today we (mostly) don't have a culture of servants, so we find it hard to understand the relationship between an employer and their personal servant, which is very close but not equal.

Comment: Concerning the German synchronisation of the film and the German translation of  translation of LotR see [here](https://unipub.uni-graz.at/obvugrhs/download/pdf/2327639?originalFilename=true). Quote from p. 102: Klar ist, dass sich durch die Filmtrilogie das Publikum stark vermehrt hat und dass der Stoff des Werks durch sie sehr viel mehr Menschen nähergebracht wurde, die die Bücher andernfalls niemals gelesen hätten. Da für die deutsche Synchronisierung der Filme die Übersetzung von Margaret Carroux zur Orientierung herangezogen wurde, hat dies vermutlich einen wichtigen Einfluss.

Comment: Quote from p. 101: Im Allgemeinen hat die Umfrage gezeigt, dass der Großteil der befragten Personen mit dem Angebot der Übersetzungen des Herrn der Ringe auf Deutsch zufrieden ist. Sie bevorzugen die Übersetzung von Margaret Carroux, vor allem weil sie ein höheres Maß an Werk- und Stiltreue aufweist und Tolkiens Buch weitgehend unverfälscht wiedergibt. Auch die Sprache, die Carroux verwendet, sagt den meisten LeserInnen mehr zu, weil sie archaischer ist und so besser in das Genre passt.

Answer (score 9):

tl;dr: The typical textbook statement "*Du* is for friends and family" is only a half-truth which applies to typical everyday situations. Originally it is simply the direct and unadorned form of address. Its use in this situation is entirely proper, and a polite form would be grossly misplaced.

---

In this specific scene I see a couple of reasons *Du* is used:

- *Du* is the most direct and natural form of address. It is the equivalent to the archaic *thou*, except that it prevailed in German everyday use. ***Thou** shalt not kill* ("Du sollst nicht töten!") is the most direct order, devoid of any considerations of form or politeness. Interestingly Du/thou is used when speaking to God as well, indicating that it does not imply talking down to someone: "Gott, mein Gott, warum hast Du mich verlassen?" ("My God, my God, why hast **thou** forsaken me?") Neither in English nor in German is this impolite or does this imply being friends. It is rather "a-polite": Not concerned with politeness. And Gandalf is similarly direct here.<sup>1</sup>
- *Ihr* or *Sie* conveys respect which Gandalf surely does not have, and politeness which would be misplaced here. You would only be polite if you wanted to preserve a smooth social relationship with somebody.
- *Du* *may* indicate a certain acquaintance. I'm not a Lord of the Rings expert but it looks as if both Gandalf and Balrogs were [*Maiars*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maia_(Middle-earth)), immortal angelic beings. *Gandalf is talking to a peer here.*

---

A side note to "Sie" vs. the archaic "Ihr" (a side note because neither of them was chosen here ;-)): The respectful pronoun *Sie* [replaced *Ihr* only in modern times](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pronominale_Anredeform) — that's why it is often not used in Fantasy settings which typically are set in a pre-industrial world.

Translations of Tolkien into German are subject to passionate debates by fans. The most modern translation by [Wolfgang Krege uses *Sie* instead of *Ihr*](https://www.ardapedia.org/wiki/Wolfgang_Krege), arguing that Tolkien essentially translated imagined extinct languages used by the protagonists into English as used in the 1940s, and that a modern translation should do the same for *their* target language, using whatever polite form of address is contemporary. That decision was much criticized.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Side note: Modern English *is already* using the polite plural form that has become archaic in German ("you" = "Ihr")! An increase in politeness must be conferred by other means, e.g. the ubiquitous "Sir" used to address customers, at least in the U.S. "Excuse me, Sir, you cannot pass here!" ;-) Why Tolkien didn't let his protagonists use the archaic *Thou* throughout is another question. The [plain answer](https://www.reddit.com/r/tolkienfans/comments/1x9pw8/use_of_thou_in_lotr/) may be that the protagonists used a different language altogether which was "translated" to (then) modern English anyway, supporting Krege's German translation approach.</sub>

Comment: German speakers seem to be much more comfortable with "Ihr" than English speaker are with "thou". Plus "Ihr" is still used in modern German; it's just restricted to nobility. (I've even seen it in futuristic science fiction.) While the English version is in 1940's language, Tolkien still avoids any slang or words that would seem out of place in a medieval setting, For example he uses "dwarves" instead of the more modern sounding "dwarfs". So while there is an argument for using "Sie", I can see why it would be avoided by most translators. It's interesting that there are exceptions though.

Comment: @RDBury "Sie" is like the store clerk's "Sir" -- English does not have the possibility to express politeness with the pronoun because you ("Ihr") have made the polite form the default and thus through inflation devalued your linguistic capital. Now you must add a polite title to be even more polite than the default :-).

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what was already written by others about the whole respect thing, I'd like to mention another aspect: Siezen is a relatively recent thing in German, [being placed around the late 17th century](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pronominale_Anredeform).

The whole concept of a Höflichkeitsform codified in German vocabulary rather than, let's say, non-verbal communication, is not that old in terms of a fantasy setting like LotR; the same Wikipedia article places the first written occurence of "Ihr" in the year 865 CE. More importantly, it was only introduced so that people from higher strata of society could feel good about being appropriately (as per them) brown-nosed by the lower classes. So why would Gandalf address *Balrog* with "Sie" or "Ihr"? "Du" is the only pronoun that makes sense.

By the way, of all people, Goethe is reknowned/infamous for subtly insulting people he didn't like or who'd given him trouble previously, in written formal correspondence by doing small things wrong, e.g. misspelling a greeting or not writing straight and level, sometimes even by choosing the wrong formal greeting on purpose. As an intelligent and learned man, he must have had a knack for sarcasm and gentle mischief. That's how I personally always imagined Gandalf, too.

Comment: 865 CE is actually *very* old for texts in the German language.

Comment: It's not very old at all for fantasy settings though. That's how I meant, but that's not at all how it reads. Bummer. I'll try to rephrase, thanks! (Edit: better now?)

Comment: A bit long now for my taste

Comment: The English "thou" form only started to be replaced by "you" in the 17th century. It's actually still used in some rural varieties of English, but I assume it's dying out under the influence of modern media. But Tolkien still used "you". (I'm pretty sure Tolkien could have written the entire novel in Old English if he'd had a mind to.) Perhaps the issue was that "thou" is associated with the Elizabethan era and out of place for use in the distant past. Better to just use modern language whenever it makes sense. It sounds like Goethe and Gandalf would have had a lot in common.

Comment: Interestingly, there has been trend among younger people in some parts of German societies, for a couple of years now, to do away again with "Sie" - perhaps as part of a desire to doing away with societal classes. There's even a few who can get offended at being "siezed" and prefer being "duzed" as well as "duzing" others.

Answer (score 2):

I am surprised that none of the answers mention the obvious:

***Sie* is reserved for people.** Germans never address non-human beings* with *Sie*. As the Balrog isn't a person†, it is addressed with *du*.

All the other arguments – that fantasy commonly uses "du", that "Sie" (or "Ihr") would be polite, that "du" is used in the book translation, that "du" is the natural form of address (whatever that is supposed to mean), that "Sie" is historically recent, etc. – are irrelevant because none of the other forms of address would apply to the Balrog under any circumstances anyway.

---

* In real life, Germans never address non-human beings with *Sie*. In fantastic literature – fairy tales, courtly romances, ballads, fantasy novels – *Sie* is reserved for beings that have personhood, that is, beings that have human nature (emotions and motivations like our own), live in some kind of society that resembles our own, etc. A fairy that lives at the court of the fairy queen would thus be addressed with *Sie*, while a fairy that lurks in a swamp or river would be addressed with *du*.

† In the English original, the pronoun for the Balrog is "it", clearly indicating that it is not a person in the same way that the hobbits, dwarves, elves, and humans are:

> The Balrog reached the bridge. ... It raised the whip, and ...

The real question then becomes: Why is the Balrog an *it* if it is a Maiar like Gandalf?

Comment: Technically, neither Gandalf or the Balrog are human, nor the Hobbits, Elves or Dwarves for that matters. As noted in one of the other answers, Gandalf and the Balrog are both Maiar, but Galdalf takes human form while the Balrog doesn't. The line between person and non-person gets blurry when you can have very non-human sentient beings.  Since posting this I've noticed that "Sie" is almost never used in high fantasy. That leaves "du" and "Ihr", and "Ihr" seems like too much respect.

Comment: @RDBury Yeah, my answer is a bit inexact due to its brevity. Honorifics can only be applied to beings that have personhood (including human nature), that is, they are intelligent, self-aware, and think, feel, and act like humans. Death, if he resembles a person, walks along the street and talks to the man or woman, may be addressed with *Ihr*. Death as a force of nature is addressed with *du*. Beings that live in a human-like society, like elves and dwarves, can be addressed with *Ihr*. Beings that are alien in their behaviour, like a monster, cannot be addressed with *Sie* or *Ihr*.

Comment: @RDBury In the orginal, Gandalf is a *he* while the Balrog is an *it*. With his use of pronouns, Tolkien has made it clear that Gandalf should be considered human-like, while the Balrog should be seen as non-human (and not a person). The translation must follow Tolkien in this and cannot ascribe personhood to the Balrog, when the author intends otherwise. Why, if they are both Maiar, one should be a person while the other is not, is not a question that a translator is qualified to answer.

Comment: As I wrote in a comment two years ago, the question is not about the English text, but  about the translator's interpretation: Why did she use "Du"? I doubt that there is a compelling linguistic reason, it is more as you say: The reader (and probably also Tolkien) does not regard  the Balrog (although a "corrupted" Maiar) as a person, but as a sort of animal. In fact, ithe Balrog makes the impression  of a dragon, and it does not talk to the  Fellowship of the Ring.

Comment: By the way, for those who understand German:  https://redaktion42.com/2013/01/02/welche-herr-der-ringe-ubersetzung-ist-die-beste/

Answer (score 0):

Monsters, demons and the like are not adressed in the "Sie" form in German because that would give them too much honour. Likewise, according to Matthew 16:23, Jesus adresses the Devil in the Du form in the German Bible translation.